# Change Tomcat log files path

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, path

I'm trying to redirect Tomcat log files into a folder of an application.

I know that I can change the path of the log files in conf/logging.properties, but I want to find a way of doing it from the application, to be able change the path depending on the application being deployed.

Is there a way of doing this?

Thanks for your time,

Comment: I don't think this would be a good idea. So if I were to install your webapp on my server its going to change where the server's log files go? Are you only interested in your webapps logs or is your app interested in the server's logs?

Comment: I'm also interested in the servers' log, that's why I'm trying to do this.

Comment: Maybe you'd like to let us know what you hope to achieve? You trying to monitor tomcat health? Is it just your web-apps you're interested in?